# Android Add button Below navigation drawer list

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want add button below the listview in navigation drawer as shown in figure.

[image]

there are custom listview with text and checkbox in navigation drawer. and i want add button below the listview. is that possible? please give me solution . thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other views below button or just a listview and button ???

Comment: If you can show some layout code that would be helpful.

Comment: yes,listview and two button below the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okk after reading your requirement i will suggest you to do this `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the button and for the list use `android:layout_above="@id/idof your button"` and `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in your listview layout.

Answer (score 2):

You must keep in mind that there can only be two **childs** at max in navigation drawer !!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightgray" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <LinearLayout 
            android:alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

           <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   
           </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
         <ListView .... here goes your navigation drawer UI/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```